# Sockets not communicating between them

Tags: sockets, zeromq, python-sockets

I am trying to do the simplest thing ever but for some reason that I cannot see (maybe because of looking for too long) is not working.

I have 2 zeromq sockets , the connection with the client thread is REQ and the connection with the broker node is ROUTER.
I removed everything not related just to find the issue , the code looks like that:

```py
import zmq
import json
from time import sleep

from threading import Thread


def client(client_name):
    print('|CLIENT {}| starting'.format(client_name))

    #  Prepare our context and sockets
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
    socket.connect("tcp://localhost:5559")

    socket.send(b'HI')
    message = socket.recv()
    print("Received reply %s" % (message))
    socket.close()
    context.term()


def broker():
    print('|BROKER| starting')

    # Prepare our context and sockets
    context = zmq.Context()
    frontend = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
    frontend.bind("tcp://*:5559")

    # Initialize poll set
    poller = zmq.Poller()
    poller.register(frontend, zmq.POLLIN)

    received = frontend.recv()
    # to_send = [[{'from': '1', 'value': 'yooooo'}, {'from': '1', 'value': 'mamamia'}], [{'from': '2', 'value': 'yooooo'}, {'from': '2', 'value': 'mamamia'}], ]
    # to_send = [0,12,6,8,3,2,10]

    frontend.send(b'OK')
    print('broker sent the message')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    broker = Thread(target=broker)
    client = Thread(target=client, args=['1', ])

    broker.start()
    client.start()

    broker.join()
    client.join()
```

And my problem is that the client never receives a message from the broker node.
I experimented with many formats, like "send_string" , "send_multipart", etc. but the problem seems to be that the client node is not receiving anything at all.

I would really appreciate some help because I am stuck at the moment with that.

Comment: Use `REP` for the broker. You can use `ROUTER` but then you need to do some additional work. Also, you don't need `Poller` for this simple setup.

Comment: Hello , the setup is based on the "Request-Reply Broker" pattern from https://zguide.zeromq.org/docs/chapter2/ (search for "figure 17") , so it is supposed to work with the REQ-ROUTER . 
If I use a REP instead of ROUTER , would the broker be able to assist many client thread requests ?

Comment: Well obviously you have missed something because it isn't working. Start simple with REQ-REP. Then extend to REQ-ROUTER but then you need to emulate the REP-REQ envelope. See [The REQ to ROUTER Combination](https://zguide.zeromq.org/docs/chapter3/#The-REQ-to-ROUTER-Combination) for details.